# Passing view controller items

Tags: ios, tableview, uistoryboardsegue

I have an IPad MasterDetail project in Xcode 7. I have set up a MasterDetail template. The TableView rows have both title and subtitle. I have the ViewController loaded with a Plist data and it is working. I can NSLog both title and subtitle values from a selected row to check that the data from a selected row is correct.

I need to pass the two values from a selected row to the DetailController. Using a segue I can pass one or the other row items but have not been able to pass both.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object for it, and pass the object:

For example:

```
class Album {
   var title: String?
   var SubTitle: String?
}
```